# prevent browse from checking manifest file

Tags: javascript, html, manifest

I'm working on an iOS web-app und i'm using HTML 5 caching features. Because of the very slow internet connection on the "server"-side (GPRS uplink), i want the prevent the browser from checking the manifest file when loading the web-app from the application cache.
I have tried to cancel the event but this doesn't work:

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking', checkingEvent, false);
function checkingEvent(e) {
   //alert('checking manifest file');
   //return false;
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

The event listeners works but the cancalling of the event doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Need more explain?? you want to disable the cache!?

Comment: No, i want to disable the cache-update. With HTML5 caching the browser compares on every page load the local manifest file with the manifest file on the server. If the file has changed, the cache will be updated. Because of the very slow internet connection i want to prevent the browser from checking the manifest-file version.

Comment: So, make the cache in one page.

Comment: Is not possible, the manifest file has to be a serparate file.

Comment: you have one manifest file then put it in the first page, the you don't have to check for it in all page it just one time.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand me correctly. I have only one page and the HTML5 application cache works without any problems.
The Problem is: the browser verifies the manifest file on every load (from the cache) of the page. I want to prevent that (reason see above).